# IplImage convert to bitmap

Tags: iplimage

I am writing a Android program which merge two video to one video. I am willing to get the IplImage from the video. According to my finding, I need to convert the Iplimage from video to bitmap then I can merge them to one picture.

So, `Tobitmap()` method is required. Can anyone give me idea on how to convert the imagebox image to bitmap base on the function?

Comment: Share what you have tried and your sample in question.

Comment: I use cvSaveImage() to save IplImage to LocalFile,then use cvLoadImage() to get Bitmap . But it works slowly in this way.